# Digitaly link between app and WP

Tags: security, windows-phone-8, digital-signature

I have a WebAPI web service which works under https protocol and WP8 app which gets the data from this web service.

I have been ask to digitally sign the app with web service. I'm not sure how can I do it or is it even possible but the idea is to make sure that just the app can access this web service.

This is how I access the web api:

```
         using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var uri = new Uri("...");

                try
                {
                    var json = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AccountSearch>>(json);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                }
                return result;
            }
```

Could you give me some ideas what should I looking for and the most official ways you guys doing that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you're accessing the webapi via webrequest class? I mean you need to attach a certificate in wp8 webrequest? or something else?

Comment: @deeiip see edited answer. I use HttpClient to get the data from web service. I don't know what I need, I'm asking what is the most official way do to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for an answer in last week and I found out that one of the best way to securely sign web service with client app is keyed-hash message authentication HMAC (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).

I found a few example how to use it but none was related to WP project.
I decided to share my solution on github:
https://github.com/greglecki/HMACSignature

Hope someone find it useful.